# Converting .jks to p12

Tags: pkcs#12, jks

How can I convert a `.jks` file to `p12`.
`jks` is a java key store file so how can I convert it to the `p12` format?

Comment: You should accept some answers to your previous questions.

Comment: @Matrix do you really find none of the answers below acceptable?  With your rep and badges, you should accept or comment as to why none of these are acceptable.

Answer (score 107):

Convert a JKS file to PKCS12 format (Java 1.6.x and above)

```
keytool \
    -importkeystore              \
    -srckeystore    KEYSTORE.jks \
    -destkeystore   KEYSTORE.p12 \
    -srcstoretype   JKS          \
    -deststoretype  PKCS12       \
    -srcstorepass   mysecret     \
    -deststorepass  mysecret     \
    -srcalias       myalias      \
    -destalias      myalias      \
    -srckeypass     mykeypass    \
    -destkeypass    mykeypass    \
    -noprompt
```

from [A few frequently used SSL commands](https://web.archive.org/web/20170107050552/http://shib.kuleuven.be/docs/ssl_commands.shtml)

Comment: Does this conversion only needs to be done for Java 1.6.x and above? I ask because I am on Java 1.7.x and faced a problem where WSKeystore class could not read the cacerts (default keystore file) until I converted it to cacerts.p12.

Comment: Note that supplying the passwords directly in the command is not a secure practice in general (as noted in the keytool manpage) as the passwords could then be read from your command history or observed with `ps`. If you omit a password, the tool should prompt you for it.

Comment: You've saved my day [Daniel Silveira](/users/1100/daniel-silveira). Thanks for the help.

Comment: "Warning:  Different store and key passwords not supported for PKCS12 KeyStores. Ignoring user-specified -destkeypass value.", https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8008292 - so if you want that, you need to use something else

Answer (score 57):

JKS → P12:

```
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore keystore.jks -srcstoretype JKS -deststoretype PKCS12 -destkeystore keystore.p12
```

P12 → JKS:

```
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore keystore.p12 -srcstoretype PKCS12 -deststoretype JKS -destkeystore keystore.jks
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is a one line command for the same.

`keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore <MY_KEYSTORE.jks> -destkeystore <MY_FILE.p12> -srcstoretype JKS -deststoretype PKCS12 -deststorepass <PASSWORD_PKCS12> -srcalias <ALIAS_SRC> -destalias <ALIAS_DEST>`

Explaining the parameters :

```
MY_FILE.p12: path to the PKCS#12 file (.p12 or .pfx extension) that is going to be created.
MY_KEYSTORE.jks: path to the keystore that you want to convert.
PASSWORD_PKCS12: password that will be requested at the PKCS#12 file opening.
ALIAS_SRC: name matching your certificate entry in the JKS keystore, "tomcat" for example.
ALIAS_DEST: name that will match your certificate entry in the PKCS#12 file, "tomcat" for example.
```

Answer (score 2):

This is for future folks, I found the above answers outdated and on mac I used this command to convert `JKS` to `PKCS12`

```
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore srckeystore.jks -destkeystore destkeystore.jks -deststoretype pkcs12
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use, https://keystore-explorer.org/
Open your jks and save as p12 or open p12 and save as jks.

Comment: Might need to right click on the key and choose export key pair instead of save as.