# RAD Workspace Errors on Startup/RAD License Conflicts

Tags: java, licensing, websphere-8, ibm-rad

*I started RAD and my workspace was full of errors.*

☞ *I get this error on every existing `.java` file that I try to open in my workspace.*

[image]

---

☞ *I get this error on my existing `.xsl` files.*

`Could not open the editor: The editor class could not be instantiated. This usually indicates a missing no-arg constructor or that the editor's class name was mistyped in plugin.xml.`

***Stack Trace:***

```
org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter$TerminatingClassNotFoundException: An error occurred while automatically activating bundle com.ibm.xtt.xsl.ui (1398).
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.wst.common.uriresolver.internal.URIResolverExtensionDescriptor.getResolver(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.wst.common.uriresolver.internal.URIResolverExtensionRegistry.getMatchingURIResolvers(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.wst.common.uriresolver.internal.ExtensibleURIResolver.resolve(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.wst.xml.core.internal.modelquery.XMLCatalogIdResolver.resolve(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.wst.xml.core.internal.modelquery.XMLModelQueryAssociationProvider.resolveGrammarURI(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.wst.xml.core.internal.contentmodel.modelqueryimpl.XMLAssociationProvider.resolveGrammarURI(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.wst.xml.core.internal.contentmodel.modelqueryimpl.CMDocumentManagerImpl.lookupOrCreateResolvedURI(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.wst.xml.core.internal.contentmodel.modelqueryimpl.CMDocumentManagerImpl.addCMDocumentReference(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.wst.xml.core.internal.contentmodel.modelqueryimpl.CMDocumentLoader.handleGrammar(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.wst.xml.core.internal.contentmodel.modelqueryimpl.CMDocumentLoader$CMDocumentLoadingNamespaceTable.addElement(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.wst.xml.core.internal.contentmodel.modelqueryimpl.CMDocumentLoader.loadCMDocuments(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.wst.xml.core.internal.contentmodel.modelqueryimpl.InferredGrammarBuildingCMDocumentLoader.loadCMDocuments(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.wst.xml.ui.internal.DOMObserver.invokeCMDocumentLoad(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.wst.xml.ui.internal.DOMObserver$TimerJob.run(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in com.ibm.xtt.xsl.ui.launch.ui.plugin.XSLLaunchUIPlugin.start() of bundle com.ibm.xtt.xsl.ui.
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.setLazyTrigger(Unknown Source)
... 27 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.ibm.cic.licensing.flexlm.FlexCheck.checkout(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.cic.licensing.common.core.LicenseChecker.requestLicense(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.cic.licensing.common.LicenseCheck.requestLicense(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.cic.licensing.common.LicenseCheck.requestLicense(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.xtt.xsl.ui.launch.ui.plugin.XSLLaunchUIPlugin.start(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Unknown Source)
... 33 more
```

---

☞ *I get this error when I try to start `WebSphere Application Server 8.5`.*

[image]

---

☞ *I get this error while trying to open existing `.jsp` files.*

`Could not open the editor: The editor class could not be instantiated. This usually indicates a missing no-arg constructor or that the editor's class name was mistyped in plugin.xml.`

***Stack Trace:***

```
org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter$TerminatingClassNotFoundException: An error occurred while automatically activating bundle com.ibm.etools.webedit.editor (802).
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.createExecutableExtension(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPlugin$1.run(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPlugin.createExtension(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.registry.EditorDescriptor.createEditor(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorManager.createPart(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.createPartHelper(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.createPart(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPartReference.getPart(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.getEditor(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busyOpenEditorBatched(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busyOpenEditor(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.access$11(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$10.run(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.ui.ide.IDE.openEditor(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.ui.ide.IDE.openEditor(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.EditorUtility.openInEditor(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.EditorUtility.openInEditor(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.OpenAction.run(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.OpenAction.run(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.SelectionDispatchAction.dispatchRun(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.SelectionDispatchAction.run(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.navigator.OpenAndExpand.run(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.ui.actions.RetargetAction.run(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.ui.navigator.CommonNavigatorManager$3.open(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.ui.OpenAndLinkWithEditorHelper$InternalListener.open(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$2.run(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil$1.run(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.fireOpen(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.handleOpen(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.ui.navigator.CommonViewer.handleOpen(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$6.handleOpen(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.fireOpenEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.access$2(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy$1.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in com.ibm.etools.webedit.editor.WebEditPlugin.start() of bundle com.ibm.etools.webedit.editor.
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.setLazyTrigger(Unknown Source)
... 81 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.ibm.cic.licensing.flexlm.FlexCheck.checkout(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.cic.licensing.common.core.LicenseChecker.requestLicense(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.cic.licensing.common.LicenseCheck.requestLicense(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.cic.licensing.common.LicenseCheck.requestLicense(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.etools.webedit.editor.WebEditPlugin.start(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Unknown Source)
... 87 more
```

*I did a workspace `clean` and restarted RAD with `-clean` but errors still show up! Any suggestions on how to fix this?*

Comment: Did it work before?  What did you do before it stopped working?

Comment: @ChrisGerken I fixed this error earlier: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20224446/how-to-view-and-edit-cacerts-file/20483171#20483171 and then I did a clean, it worked fine yesterday. I closed the workspace then and opened today only to find these errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Folks, it appears the problem was with the `license configuration for RAD`.  Recently the license on my workstation was switched from a `Floating` to a `Permanent` license and then the desktop team reassigned the permanent install and removed the floating install assignment.  When that happened, `Installation Manager was confused on which license to use`. When the floating license was disabled, it picked up the permanent license and got me rid of all the errors. Thanks to our Systems Engineer!

[image]

Hope this helps someone!