# Tried to create a client certificate with keytool, but Firefox doesn't accept it

Tags: certificate, client, keytool

I'm trying to create a client certificate for development purposes but Firefox doesn't accept it and Chrome says "ok" but doesn't list it. I suspect that is something related with CA, but anyway I recognize it's a clear lack of basics problem.

The steps I've followed:

1: Create the cert

```
$>keytool -genkey -alias dev -keystore mystore.jks -validity 3650
```

The cert created is supposed to be self-signed.

2: Export the cert

```
$>keytool -export -alias dev -keystore mystore.jks -file dev.crt
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

FF doesn't accept your certificate because it expects pkcs12 format. Convert your cert to pkcs12 and import will work. See [Converting .jks to p12](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846828/converting-jks-to-p12).
It looks that Chrome works better with pkcs12 as well.