# WebLogic javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat, ssl, weblogic12c

My application needs to connect to webservice to some stuff. This was working fine when my application was deployed over tomcate, however when I deployed my application over weblogic I got:

```
com.sun.xml.ws.client.ClientTransportException: HTTP transport error:
    javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: General SSLEngine problem
```

Does anyone has an idea what I am missing or if there is any added configuration I should add. Also kindly note that I enabled the SSL connections for weblogic but still having same problem.
Added stack trace below

```
Exception caught HTTP transport error: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: General SSLEngine problem
com.sun.xml.ws.client.ClientTransportException: HTTP transport error: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: General SSLEngine problem
        at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpClientTransport.getOutput(HttpClientTransport.java:131)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.process(HttpTransportPipe.java:223)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.processRequest(HttpTransportPipe.java:145)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.DeferredTransportPipe.processRequest(DeferredTransportPipe.java:110)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:1136)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:1050)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:1019)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:877)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.client.Stub.process(Stub.java:463)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.doProcess(SEIStub.java:191)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:108)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:92)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:161)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy93.getSubscriberAllInf(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.spi.ClientInstanceInvocationHandler.invoke(ClientInstanceInvocationHandler.java:87)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy94.getSubscriberAllInf(Unknown Source)
        at com.asset.chargingsystem.webservices.pcrfnew.PCRFHandler.executeAllSubscriberInfoPCRFAction(PCRFHandler.java:51)
        at com.asset.chargingsystem.components.PCRFInquireSubscriberInfo.doOperation(PCRFInquireSubscriberInfo.java:73)
        at com.asset.chargingsystem.controller.MainController.routeRequest(MainController.java:539)
        at com.asset.chargingsystem.controller.MainController.routeRequest(MainController.java:544)
        at com.asset.chargingsystem.controller.MainController.routeRequest(MainController.java:544)
        at com.asset.chargingsystem.interfaces.Inquiry.performTask(Inquiry.java:97)
        at com.asset.chargingsystem.interfaces.Inquiry.doGet(Inquiry.java:245)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:844)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:280)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:254)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:136)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:346)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:25)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
        at com.asset.chargingsystem.interfaces.CIFilter.doFilter(CIFilter.java:37)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestEventsFilter.doFilter(RequestEventsFilter.java:27)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3436)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3402)
        at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
        at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
        at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2285)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2201)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2179)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1572)
        at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:255)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:311)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:263)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: General SSLEngine problem
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.checkThrown(Handshaker.java:1290)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.checkTaskThrown(SSLEngineImpl.java:513)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.writeAppRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:1177)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.wrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:1149)
        at javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.wrap(SSLEngine.java:469)
        at weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter.JaSSLEngine$1.run(JaSSLEngine.java:68)
        at weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter.JaSSLEngine.doAction(JaSSLEngine.java:734)
        at weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter.JaSSLEngine.wrap(JaSSLEngine.java:66)
        at weblogic.socket.JSSEFilterImpl.wrapAndWrite(JSSEFilterImpl.java:716)
        at weblogic.socket.JSSEFilterImpl.doHandshake(JSSEFilterImpl.java:107)
        at weblogic.socket.JSSEFilterImpl.doHandshake(JSSEFilterImpl.java:75)
        at weblogic.socket.JSSESocket.startHandshake(JSSESocket.java:219)
        at weblogic.net.http.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:563)
        at weblogic.net.http.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:534)
        at weblogic.net.http.HttpsURLConnection.connect(HttpsURLConnection.java:248)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpClientTransport.getOutput(HttpClientTransport.java:129)
        ... 50 more
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: General SSLEngine problem
        at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.fatal(SSLEngineImpl.java:1683)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:278)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:270)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1341)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:153)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:868)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$1.run(Handshaker.java:808)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$1.run(Handshaker.java:806)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$DelegatedTask.run(Handshaker.java:1227)
        at weblogic.socket.JSSEFilterImpl.doTasks(JSSEFilterImpl.java:205)
        at weblogic.socket.JSSEFilterImpl.doHandshake(JSSEFilterImpl.java:111)
        ... 56 more
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:385)
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:292)
        at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:326)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:231)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:107)
        at weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter.JaTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(JaTrustManager.java:128)
        at sun.security.ssl.AbstractTrustManagerWrapper.checkServerTrusted(SSLContextImpl.java:827)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1328)
        ... 64 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:196)
        at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:268)
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:380)
        ... 72 more
20150713_00:25:34:892|DEBUG|[[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '3' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)']|[PCRFHandler][executeAllSubscriberInfoPCRFAction()] End executePCRFAction with action [getAllSubscriberInfo] in 3919 msecs
20150713_00:25:34:893|ERROR|[[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '3' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)']|[Landline number = 02211223344][DeleteService][doOperation()] Exception --> HTTP transport error: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: General SSLEngine problem
com.sun.xml.ws.client.ClientTransportException: HTTP transport error: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: General SSLEngine problem
        at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpClientTransport.getOutput(HttpClientTransport.java:131)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.process(HttpTransportPipe.java:223)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.processRequest(HttpTransportPipe.java:145)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.DeferredTransportPipe.processRequest(DeferredTransportPipe.java:110)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:1136)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:1050)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:1019)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:877)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.client.Stub.process(Stub.java:463)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.doProcess(SEIStub.java:191)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:108)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:92)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:161)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy93.getSubscriberAllInf(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.spi.ClientInstanceInvocationHandler.invoke(ClientInstanceInvocationHandler.java:87)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy94.getSubscriberAllInf(Unknown Source)
        at com.asset.chargingsystem.webservices.pcrfnew.PCRFHandler.executeAllSubscriberInfoPCRFAction(PCRFHandler.java:51)
        at com.asset.chargingsystem.components.PCRFInquireSubscriberInfo.doOperation(PCRFInquireSubscriberInfo.java:73)
        at com.asset.chargingsystem.controller.MainController.routeRequest(MainController.java:539)
        at com.asset.chargingsystem.controller.MainController.routeRequest(MainController.java:544)
        at com.asset.chargingsystem.controller.MainController.routeRequest(MainController.java:544)
        at com.asset.chargingsystem.interfaces.Inquiry.performTask(Inquiry.java:97)
        at com.asset.chargingsystem.interfaces.Inquiry.doGet(Inquiry.java:245)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:844)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:280)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:254)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:136)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:346)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:25)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
        at com.asset.chargingsystem.interfaces.CIFilter.doFilter(CIFilter.java:37)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestEventsFilter.doFilter(RequestEventsFilter.java:27)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3436)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3402)
        at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
        at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
        at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2285)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2201)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2179)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1572)
        at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:255)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:311)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:263)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: General SSLEngine problem
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.checkThrown(Handshaker.java:1290)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.checkTaskThrown(SSLEngineImpl.java:513)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.writeAppRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:1177)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.wrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:1149)
        at javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.wrap(SSLEngine.java:469)
        at weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter.JaSSLEngine$1.run(JaSSLEngine.java:68)
        at weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter.JaSSLEngine.doAction(JaSSLEngine.java:734)
        at weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter.JaSSLEngine.wrap(JaSSLEngine.java:66)
        at weblogic.socket.JSSEFilterImpl.wrapAndWrite(JSSEFilterImpl.java:716)
        at weblogic.socket.JSSEFilterImpl.doHandshake(JSSEFilterImpl.java:107)
        at weblogic.socket.JSSEFilterImpl.doHandshake(JSSEFilterImpl.java:75)
        at weblogic.socket.JSSESocket.startHandshake(JSSESocket.java:219)
        at weblogic.net.http.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:563)
        at weblogic.net.http.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:534)
        at weblogic.net.http.HttpsURLConnection.connect(HttpsURLConnection.java:248)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpClientTransport.getOutput(HttpClientTransport.java:129)
        ... 50 more
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: General SSLEngine problem
        at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.fatal(SSLEngineImpl.java:1683)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:278)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:270)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1341)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:153)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:868)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$1.run(Handshaker.java:808)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$1.run(Handshaker.java:806)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$DelegatedTask.run(Handshaker.java:1227)
        at weblogic.socket.JSSEFilterImpl.doTasks(JSSEFilterImpl.java:205)
        at weblogic.socket.JSSEFilterImpl.doHandshake(JSSEFilterImpl.java:111)
        ... 56 more
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:385)
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:292)
        at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:326)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:231)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:107)
        at weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter.JaTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(JaTrustManager.java:128)
        at sun.security.ssl.AbstractTrustManagerWrapper.checkServerTrusted(SSLContextImpl.java:827)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1328)
        ... 64 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:196)
        at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:268)
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:380)
        ... 72 more
```

Comment: Have you added ssl certificate in weblogic?

Comment: And how this can be done?

Comment: First tell me webservice is on https or http?

Comment: The webservice is https

Comment: Please post the entire stack trace.

Comment: @Islam Try adding public certificate in jre used by weblogic. I don't know how to find jre used by weblogic. But once you get jre use keytool command to import public certificates issued by website where web service is deployed.

Comment: Did you read any of the steps at? http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24422/identity_trust.htm#SECMG382 You will need to configure your server certs - you can do it in the admin console at `servers -> server name -> configuration -> ssl/keystores` This is basic setup for weblogic

Comment: I doubt that this has anything to do with certificates. There are specific exceptions for that.

Comment: @EJP the same application with same code is already running on tomcat server, so if you doubt it is not certificates what should it be? I think it must be some configuration from weblogic, do not know if it is certificates or not,  I will try and feedback.

Comment: @Islam, to debug SSL related issue on weblogic you need to do some settings set `-Dweblogic.StdoutDebugEnabled=true`, `-Dssl.debug=true ` and `-Djavax.net.debug=all`. after this debug trace is generated looking into that we can trace the issue.

Comment: Generally when I have seen these errors it is a cert problem OR a java security setting (wrong crypto jars, wrong providers, etc.). Have you modified the standard JDK install in some way? Is `-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/path/to/cacerts.jks` set?

Answer (score 2):

- You could either import the corresponding SSL certificate (or its CA) into the WebLogic trust store (e.g. as described here: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/web.1111/e13707/identity_trust.htm#SECMG379) as already suggested by Amogh.
- Or if you prefer to use the default Java (SUN) SSL stack and your code already uses a properly configured SSLContext (as you write that it worked for Tomcat, this could be already the case), avoid the usage of the WebLogic SSL stack by providing `-DUseSunHttpHandler=true` for `JAVA_OPTIONS` in `setDomainEnv.[cmd|sh]`.

Comment: I had to use the SUN SSL option, because the setting of *weblogic.security.SSL.TrustManager* accepting all certs, is not working for me. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62347630/weblogic-uses-configured-keystore-even-if-the-trustmanager-accepting-all-certs-i It may be only WLS configuration issue, but I didn't find anything mentioned in ORA examples documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Islam ...I would suggest you to check below (both client and server side)

1. Upgrade to the latest jdk at both sides
2. check TLS versions 
   for eg,. -Djdk.tls.client.protocols=TLSv1.2 -Dweblogic.security.SSL.minimumProtocolVersion=TLSv1.2
3. Check ciphers at both ends (domain/config/config.xml). make sure atleast 2 matches
   4.ssl certs both ends

If you still see the issue, please enable below and restart the jvm
-Dssl.debug=true -Dweblogic.security.SSL.verbose=true -Dweblogic.StdoutDebugEnabled=true -Djavax.net.debug=all -Djava.security.debug=all -Dweblogic.wsee.security.verbose=true -Dweblogic.wsee.security.debug=true -Dweblogic.webservice.verbose=true

Answer (score 0):

ask the webservice server admin for pfx file .then follow the procedure .Answer given at

[Import PFX file into Existing JKS file (NOT converting from .pfx to .jks)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26808193/import-pfx-file-into-existing-jks-file-not-converting-from-pfx-to-jks)