# Weblogic uses configured keystore even if the TrustManager accepting all certs is configured for SSLContext

Tags: java, ssl, weblogic

I'm using WebLogic **12.2.1.3.0** and **JDK8** to run following part of code in my PoC application deployed. Application uses *weblogic.net.http.HttpsURLConnection* client class:

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.security.Provider;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;

import javax.net.ssl.SSLSession;

import weblogic.net.http.HttpURLConnection;
import weblogic.net.http.HttpsURLConnection;
import weblogic.security.SSL.HostnameVerifier;
import weblogic.security.SSL.SSLContext;
import weblogic.security.SSL.SSLSocketFactory;
import weblogic.security.SSL.TrustManager;

...

        HttpURLConnection con = null;

        if (url.startsWith("https")) {

            HostnameVerifier hv = new HostnameVerifier() {              
                @Override
                public boolean verify(String arg0, SSLSession arg1) {
                    return true;
                }
            }; 

            TrustManager tm = new TrustManager() {

                @Override
                public boolean certificateCallback(X509Certificate[] arg0, int arg1) {
                    return true;
                }
            };

            SSLContext ctx = SSLContext.getInstance("https");
            ctx.setHostnameVerifier(hv);
            ctx.setTrustManager(tm);

            SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = ctx.getSocketFactory();
            con = new HttpsURLConnection(new URL(url));
            ((HttpsURLConnection)con).setSSLSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory);

            //con = new HttpsURLConnection(new URL(url));
        } else {
            con = new HttpURLConnection(new URL(url));
        }

        con.setReadTimeout(10*1000); //ms
        con.setRequestMethod("POST");               
        con.setRequestProperty("Content-length", "" + msg.length());
        con.setRequestProperty("Content-type", "application/octet-stream");
        con.setDoOutput(true);
        con.connect();
...
```

this is based on Oracle WLS examples: [wls/SCPRG/ssl_client.htm](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/wls/SCPRG/ssl_client.htm#SCPRG244)

it works only if I configure the CA root certificate into trusted keystore. It doesn't reflect setting my SSLContext with TrustManager (accepting all certs) and it works same way as without my SSLContext specified. My self signed root CA of the server which client connects have to be include in keystore, otherwise WLS raises:

```
        at com.poc.PoCServlet.doGet(PoCServlet.java:24)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:286)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:260)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:137)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:350)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:247)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3697)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3667)
        at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:326)
        at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAsForUserCode(SecurityManager.java:197)
        at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSecurityProvider.runAsForUserCode(WlsSecurityProvider.java:203)
        at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:71)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2443)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2291)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2269)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.runInternal(ServletRequestImpl.java:1703)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1663)
        at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:272)
        at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:352)
        at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:337)
        at weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:57)
        at weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41)
        at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:644)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:415)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:355)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: General SSLEngine problem
        at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.fatal(SSLEngineImpl.java:1709)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:318)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:310)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1639)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:223)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:1037)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$1.run(Handshaker.java:970)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$1.run(Handshaker.java:967)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$DelegatedTask.run(Handshaker.java:1459)
        at weblogic.socket.JSSEFilterImpl.doTasks(JSSEFilterImpl.java:223)
        at weblogic.socket.JSSEFilterImpl.doHandshake(JSSEFilterImpl.java:123)
        ... 34 common frames omitted
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:397)
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:302)
        at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:262)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:324)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:229)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:105)
        at weblogic.security.SSL.jsseadapter.JaTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(JaTrustManager.java:128)
        at sun.security.ssl.AbstractTrustManagerWrapper.checkServerTrusted(SSLContextImpl.java:1006)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1626)
        ... 42 common frames omitted
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141)
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126)
        at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:280)
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:392)
        ... 50 common frames omitted
```

I like to accept all the (client connecting) servers certificated (as default) in my client implementation, regardless the WebLogic server (where is my https connection implemented and deployed as part of web application) keystore content.

**--UPDATE--**

When I add output to the weblogic.security.SSL.TrustManager interface implementation, this is not displayed, so TrustManager method is not called.

Comment: Can you clarify a little bit more your goal with your code ? What are you trying to do exactly ?
The Oracle documentation explains how to configure WebLogic Server is SSL mode. So, all incoming ssl requests will be handled by WebLogic before any application code deployed into the domain.

Comment: This code is part of server application (there is a reason why I can't use e.g. appache http client), this server application connects other service over https (using only WebLogic API) and default configuration (if the trusted keystore is NOT explicitly configured) is accept all the certificates, using  method 'certificateCallback' overriding returns true for all certs.

Comment: I have the same issue with Weblogic 14, did you find the reason?

Comment: Same issue in Weblogic 12.2.1.4. Have you found any solution to avoid importing the certificate?

Comment: No still using the configuration workaround and WLS client side still not accept TrustManager setter of SSLContext