# How to add keystore file in jenkins?

Tags: android, jenkins, android-keystore

I had created keystore file from android studio and now I want to use it in jenkins. SO from where i can add keystore file for generate signed apk in jenkins.
Because when i am clicking on Key Store it shows nothing.

[image]

Comment: try to conve your keystore file first.
converting-jks-to-p12
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846828/converting-jks-to-p12

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you configure it in configuration tools in manage jenkins.