# Import Keystore and Truststore to Azure Key vault

Tags: azure, ssl, ssl-certificate, azure-keyvault

I have an SSL certificate `client.ks` & `client.ts` that I would like to import into Azure Key Vault but it only accepts `.PEM` format.

I tried to concatenate the two files into one via `cat client.ks client.ts > client.pem` but I got the error when loading it:

> The specified PEM X.509 certificate content can not be read. Please check if certificate is valid PEM format.

Any suggestions into how I get those two files in the keyvault ?

Answer (score 0):

You can store any file as a keyvault Secret if you base64 encode it and the total size is less then 25kb.

For example from the cli:

```
OUTPUT="$(base64 -w0 < example.txt)" & az keyvault secret set --name mysecret --vault-name myvault --value $OUTPUT
```

When retrieving the secret you can decode it and write the output to file.

For more details refer this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61486891/how-to-store-a-keystore-in-microsoft-azure-vault)